# Rails Variable from Application Layout Not accessible from View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to pass my page's title as a hidden variable to a form (to get at the source of newly-registering users), but am having some issues.

I have this in my application to set the variable of a page's title:

```
<% if content_for?(:title) %>
  <% @page_title = yield(:title) %>
<% end %>
```

Which I know is working because if I put this as a test later in my `application.html.erb` it displays the page title correctly ("Page Title: Correct Title Here":

```
<%= "Page Title: " + @page_title.to_s %>
```

However, if I go to one of the views using this application layout and put the same thing:

```
<%= "Page Title: " + @page_title.to_s %>
```

It just displays "Page Title: " but no page title.

What am I missing that this variable will display when the application template calls it, but not the `yield`ed view?

Comment: recheck that with a default title.  `@page_title = yield(:title) || "default title" `

Comment: @Mezbah double checked and it has the same issue.